# CodeIgniter: Case in where clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

How do we state the `case` in `where` clause condition in CodeIgniter's active record?

Here is the query I want to achieve

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE idx =5342 and CASE WHEN reserve_date = 20151130 THEN reserve_time > 1537 ELSE reserve_date > 20151130 END
```

I tried to search on Google about this question but still could not find any answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write your condition in `where clause`

```
$this->db->select("*");
$this->db->where("idx",5342);
$this->db->where("CASE WHEN reserve_date = 20151130 THEN reserve_time > 1537 ELSE reserve_date > 20151130 END");
$query=$this->db->get("table");
```

Comment: I thought there was another way for this.

Comment: where condition can accept any type of string  in codeignitor. and there is so such way to write when condition query in codeignitor

Comment: I believe that 2 where calls will be better in this case .

Comment: @Svetlio yep it would be better if we split where condition.

Comment: If I want to use case in db select then what it would be ?? such as
SELECT CASE
    WHEN user_status = 1 THEN 'active'
    WHEN user_status = 0 THEN 'inactive'
    ELSE 'baz'
END AS staus
FROM users